# Differences in word counts in two files

Tags: python, strings, file

How can I change my two functions to be more readable functions (i.e. in steps), because I am using pycharm.

```
import collections

def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):

    mylist1 = []
    mylist2 = []
    with open(fpath1, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        for line1 in f:
            for word in line1.split(" "):
                if word.strip('\n'):
                    mylist1.append(word.strip())
    with open(fpath2, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as x:
        for line2 in x:
            for word in line2.split(" "):
                if word.strip('\n'):
                    mylist2.append(word.strip())

    if mylist1==0 and mylist2==0:
        return None

    c=collections.Counter(mylist1)
    c.subtract(mylist2)
    return c
```

Answer (score 2):

Change lines like this:

```
    for word in line1.split(" "):
```

To lines like:

```
    for word in (w.strip() for w in line1.split(" ")):
```

**UPDATE:**

Here are two ways you could tighten up your function:

1:

```
    def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):

        count = collections.Counter()
        with open(fpath1, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as fp:
            for line in f:
                count.update([w.strip() for word in line.split()])
        with open(fpath2, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                count.subtract([w.strip() for word in line.split()])

        return len(counter) and counter or none
```

2:

```
    def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):

        def get_words(path):
            words = []
            with open(path, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as fp:
                for line1 in f:
                    words.extend([w.strip() for word in line.split()])

        counter = collections.Counter(get_words(fpath1))
        counter.subtract(get_words(fpath2))

        return len(counter) and counter or none
```

Comment: +one. better than my suggestion in the comment above. And pythonic. And uses a generator expression.

Comment: is there any possible way to make my function more readable because it looks complicated to me

Comment: i updated my post , Can someone please edit my function to simpler way

Comment: Instead of `(w.strip() for w in line1.split(" "))` you could use `map`: `map(str.strip, line1.split())`. You also don't need to pass `" "` to `split` since it will automatically default to splitting based on whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `for` loops can be changed to:

```
with open(fpath1, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
         mylist1.append(word.strip() for word in line.split())
with open(fpath2, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
         mylist2.append(word.strip() for word in line.split())
```

At this point in time one realises that these loops are a little to similar, so let us continue with joining them into something like:

```
for filepath in (fpath1, fpath2):
    with open(filepath, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            mylistX.append(word.strip() for word in line.split())
```

But then we see that we can't append everything into `mylist1` or `mylist2`, which already in the names are indicating with the addition of `1` and `2` that they should really be an array already. So lets do that:

```
lists = []
for filepath in (fpath1, fpath2):
    tmp_list = []
    with open(filepath, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            tmp_list.append(word.strip() for word in line.split())

    lists.append(tmp_list)
```

And then to wrap it up we need some changes to the end of the code to adjust to the newly created list of lists:

```
if len(lists[0]) == 0 or len(lists[1]) == 0:
    return None

counter = collections.Counter(lists[0])
    counter.subtract(lists[1])
    return counter
```

It is left as an exercise for the user to extend the parameters into a list of filepaths, and extend the logic to return a counter with all remaining files subtracted if that is a wanted extension.